# Data binding causing WPF designer error

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, designer

Does anyone know why this binding is causing an error in the WPF designer? ("Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.")

XAML (partial):

```
<Window xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyAppNamespace">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Clients.Instance},
                                    Path=ClientList}" />
</Window>
```

C#:

```
namespace MyAppNamespace
{
    public sealed class Clients
    {
        // Singleton pattern
        public static readonly Clients Instance = new Clients();
        private Clients() { }
        static Clients()
        {
            clientList = new ObservableCollection<Client>();
            PopulateClientList();
        }

        private static ObservableCollection<Client> clientList;
        public static ObservableCollection<Client> ClientList
        {
            get { return clientList; }
            set { clientList = value; }
        }

        public static void PopulateClientList()
        {
            // .. load client data from xml
        }

        public class Client
        {
            // ... expose public properties for fields in provided xml element
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Charlie He is not binding member variable...

Comment: I don't see any problem with this code... is it just problem with designer or are you not able to compile it?

Comment: Just in the designer. It compiles and executes correctly!

Comment: The designer is pretty buggy, so it could just be another random designer fail.  The first thing to do is to drill into that TargetInvocationException the designer is reporting and look at the InnerException.  That will tell you the real problem.  If the designer isn't showing the InnerException, attach a debugger to VS, set it to break when TIE is thrown and examine the TIE in the debugger.  My guess would be that PopulateClientList is throwing an exception, which would result in a TypeLoadException (because it's called from the static ctor); again drill in to find the real exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would bet there's some code inside PopulateClientList() that's failing when run from the AppDomain the designer is running the code from.

If you're loading XML from a file, maybe the physical path isn't in the same relative location, or something like that.

Comment: Per my comment above, he can drill down through InnerException to verify this hunch and determine the original cause.

Comment: Correct answer! The path to my XML file was flummoxing the designer...  System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)

Answer (score 1):

try replacing your include statement with "clr-namespace:MyAppNamespace;assembly=" adding the assembly. you dont have to enter the assembly name. its a bug with visual studio.